# C++ STL memory management in containers

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks, stl

I'm coding some mission critical code that I have to make sure it's absolutely free of memory leaks. I've wrote a small function that allows me to retrieve the memory usage at runtime and I make measurements before and after executing some code (that should be leak free) to see if memory usage remains on the same level.

While debugging a piece of code that was 'leaking', I finally found the culprit to be a vector container.

The minimal code that reproduces what I'm seeing is the following:

```
vector<char*>* v = new vector<char*>();
int n = 1024*1024;
while (n--)
{
     v->push_back(new char[256]()); // A
}
for (vector<char*>::iterator it=v->begin() ; it!=v->end() ; ++it )
{
     delete[] (*it);
}
delete v;
```

If you run that code (disabling compiler optimizations of course, `-O0`) and put some trap at the end so that the program doesn't exit (like `cin.ignore();`) you would see that your program should be using around 20Mb or so of memory.

I'd like to understand why does that happen. There's a line I marked with `A`, where if you allocate a larger char array you would see that the 'remaining' memory at the end is larger too. I wouldn't call this a leak per se beause apparently that memory could be reused if I allocate and fill another STL container, but still I would have expected to have that memory completely freed when the code finishes.

Can someone shed some light on to why is this memory still being used? And how may I 'free' it for real?

Some details about my compiler environment:

```
Using clang++: Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.51) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix

Compiling with: g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -O0 main.cc -o main.out
```

Comment: Why would you want to use vector<char*> instead of vector<vector<char>> !?

Comment: I'm just using that char* to allocate an arbitrary amount of memory. In practice, you could use any kind of type there and you would still observe this behavior.

Comment: You seem to be expecting that the memory manager would actually deallocate the memory from your process just because you freed it, but that's not how it generally works. It's just virtual memory, anyway, so as long as your process is not using it, it doesn't take up any RAM. And, as you said, if you ask for more memory that memory will be reused.

Comment: @Deduplicator You could try running the code with vector<string>* instead and allocate everything in your preferred way. You would still observe this behavior.

Comment: Looking at the memory usage in the system monitor or the like is definitely the wrong way to check for leaks and you'll be hunting for ghosts everywhere.

Comment: Thanks @ooga, I believed it should had to be something like that. However, how come when I explicitly alloc/release memory that memory is actually deallocated and somehow memory used by STL containers is not? Is there a way to force some kind of 'garbage collection' on this 'reserved' memory? I actually need it that way.

Comment: @almosnow: You could provide your own allocator. That would be highly non-trivial though. However, you should most definitely not be using `new` and `delete` directly- always use a containing class. Else you WILL suffer many memory leaks. STL containers is nothing special in this regard- the runtime caches the memory from the OS in the same way regardless of who asks for it.

Comment: @almosnow if performance is a criteria, i'd highly recommend to consider `v->reserve(n);` before starting the pushbacks.  This could avoid that your vector constantly has to reallocate memory as it increases, possibly moving it's elements and creating heap fragmentation.

Comment: @almosnow Just to be clear, the preferred way is *not* `vector<string>*`, it’s `vector<string>`. I actually cringed reading the code. That said, yes, it’s unrelated here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is no excuse for dynamically allocating your container in your scenario. Why?

Second, it's a container of `char*`, and while it is responsible for managing those, you retain full and sole responsibility for whatever they point (or don't point) to!

Consider using `vector<char>`, `unique_ptr<char>`, `string` or something like that as the element-type to let the `vector` take that task.

Finally, keep in mind that the runtime-system uses its own allocator built on the OS primitives, so allocating memory does not directly translate to a request to the OS, nor does freeing / deleting it immediately return it there.
Doing so **would be incredibly inefficient**.

If you *really* want to make sure freed memory is returned to the OS, you have basically two options (which both involve writing your own allocator, or finding and using one someone else built):

- Replace the replacable global allocation and deallocation functions with your own.
- Use your own allocator for just those allocations (standard-containers are allocator-aware, which means you can provide your own allocator on a per-container basis).

After you are done, just ask your allocator to release everything back to the OS.

Comment: Hits all the right points. Not using RAII is insane if you have to guarantee no leaks, and measuring active memory is very flawed when runtime allocator caches are not taken into account.

Comment: This is in no way related to RAII. You could try writing your own code and see that you will end up finding the same behavior. Measuring memory *could be* very flawed, but you guys have no guarantee that I'm doing it right or wrong. I believe I was clear enough when explaining the overall situation/behavior so that these kind of comments wouldn't appear. Anyway, thanks Puppy for the allocator hint, I would try to implement a custom allocator and see if I can get rid of the problem that way.

Comment: @almosnow: Yes, you are not directly asking about RAII, and if you reduced your question to what you wanted to actually ask about (missing memory-footprint-reduction after `delete`), I could remove the first part. It's still invaluable advice, and I would have been justly criticized had I failed to very prominently warn you about that. Still, I'm also answering the question you actually asked.

Comment: Thanks @Deduplicator, but what I'm asking is why is this memory still being used? (because it may get used in the future, yeah but why and how does STL do that?) and how should I ensure that it gets freed?

Comment: As I said, it *is* freed (back to the runtime-system). And there are excellent reasons the runtime-system does not return it to the operating-system (yet). Added something about how you can force freeing it back to the OS. (And the STL *does not* retain the memory, the allocator, which is part of the standard-library does. BTW: STL is the wrong term even for the container-part of the standard-library, which is STL-derived.)

Comment: Yeah, I'll resort to write my own allocators. Or maybe my own vector implementation (which seems really easy to do for what I want it to do). I wanted to see if someone with a deep knowledge of STL could point to some kind of obscure std::release_memory_immediately() function or flag or whatever and save me the hard work. But still, thanks.

Comment: Oh, yeah that's it. Do know if there's some way to 'flush' the default allocator's memory or anything like that?

Comment: No need to go whole hog and replace everything, just a custom allocator is plenty work enough. And the standard library does not provide a "release to OS what you can"-function. I doubt most allocators do that either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66369/discussion-between-almosnow-and-deduplicator).